# what distinguishes object-oriented programming from programming with abstract data types (polymorphism)

Tags: java, android

As I was going through this [java world article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-2001/jw-1012-designpatterns.html), it make reference to this. I tried to look through documentation, but could not find anything.

Comment: That article was written in 2001.  I would try and find something more updated.

Comment: I agree with trevor, just by reading the wiki article should make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Polymorphism is just one of the governing principles of object oriented programming.

A program that is designed in an object-oriented style is one that uses classes to encapsulate individual pieces of functionality (encapsulation) and separates design from implementation (abstraction) using interfaces and/or abstract classes.

If you like, "OOP includes polymorphism", but "polymorphism by itself is not enough to define OOP".